# Laravel5.2 error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel

Suddenly, my page brings two errors. but I don't know about this error. Help!

1/2

```
ErrorException in e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php line 198:
Trying to get property of non-object

in e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php line 198
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object','/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/framework/views/e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php', '198', array('__path' => '/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/framework/views/e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'boards' => object(board), 'comments' => object(LengthAwarePaginator), 'replies' => object(Collection)), 'obLevel' => '1', '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'boards' => object(board), 'comments' => object(LengthAwarePaginator), 'replies' => object(Collection), 'comment' => object(comment), 'reply' => object(comment))) in e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php line 198
at include('/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/framework/views/e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/framework/views/e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'boards' => object(board), 'comments' => object(LengthAwarePaginator), 'replies' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/views/board/show.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'boards' => object(board), 'comments' => object(LengthAwarePaginator), 'replies' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 149
.... blah
```

2/2

```
ErrorException in e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php line 198:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/views/board/show.blade.php)

in e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php line 198
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/framework/views/e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'boards' => object(board), 'comments' => object(LengthAwarePaginator), 'replies' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/views/board/show.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'boards' => object(board), 'comments' => object(LengthAwarePaginator), 'replies' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 149
.... blah
```

this page is loading successfull before . I think some typo exist in my controller, view file , and something but I can't find that.

/storage/framework/views folder for the e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php file 
include line 198

```
var reply_form = reply_form+'<form action="<?php echo e(route('comment.store')); ?>" method="post">';
            var reply_form = reply_form+'<input type="hidden" name="page_no" value="<?php echo e($boards->id); ?>">';
            var reply_form = reply_form+'<input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="'+p_article_id+'">';
            var reply_form = reply_form+'<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo e(csrf_token()); ?>">';
            var reply_form = reply_form+'<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo e(Auth::user()->name); ?>">';
            var reply_form = reply_form+'<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo e(Auth::user()->email); ?>">';// 198 line
            var reply_form = reply_form+'<textarea name="comment" placeholder="내용을 입력해주세요"></textarea>';
            var reply_form = reply_form+'<input type="submit" value="등록">';
            var reply_form = reply_form+'</form>';
```

Comment: Check `show.blade.php` page on line no 198. You are accessing the property of object which is not exists

Comment: check the /storage/framework/views folder for the e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php file and look at line 198. On that line you probable try to acces a parameter of an object which is non existent (null)

Comment: /storage/framework/views folder for the e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php file 198 line : var reply_form = reply_form+'<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo e(Auth::user()->name); ?>">'; in <script> tag. Is this code has some problem? I think It's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open that specific view file `resources/views/board/show.blade.php`, go to `line 198`. Here check what you are trying to access that really don't exists.

Comment: It's just empty line in <script> tag. And I edit something or delete something, error doesn't changed

Comment: And It's same code with before code , It worked before

Comment: Run `php artisan clear-compiled` to clear compiled view files and then check again. If it's still exists, then please paste your view code.

Comment: Runnin' php artisan clear-compiled cant remove this errors. How can I show this code?

Comment: can't add all of my codes, I tried to edit my article , but so many error occur

Comment: Oh! while generating the views for the user is the user logged in or a guest user ?

Comment: I edit  
/storage/framework/views folder for the e7e9061cce284d56f8d5e5f1771eed43d8f09c38.php file 198 line :  and some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125484/discussion-between-mahfuzul-alam-and-).